# Converting System.Object to Custom Object after use in a stack?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a stack to store Card objects but I can't find a way to either get the stack to pop a card object or to convert a System.object to my Card object.

The error I'm getting is: Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Card'

So I look into it a little more, and it turns out I had no idea what boxing and unboxing were but I managed to get it fixed just by adding (card) before the pop(), thanks for all the help everyone!!

Comment: Every instance can be casted to the object type in C# (or "boxed" to such a type). And the stack has the pop/peek methods to do what you are trying to do. Please post the code you have the problem at so we may understand a little better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't think anybody knows what exactly you are talking about. Can you please show some code?

Comment: What have you already tried? What errors have you got? Provide us some code or else we won't be able to help you.

Comment: At such a beginner level it's seems strange you are bothering about such stuff.  Just use a List<> and add and subtract from the end of the list, if that's what you want to do.  I cannot see the slightest reason you would even need to *know* what a Stack is, far less ever use one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a generic stack

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx

For example

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

var stack = new Stack<Card>();
stack.Push(new Card());

Card card = stack.Pop()
```

should do what you want.

EDIT:

Ok, after your edit I think the problem is here:

```
object temp;
object[] array = new object[n];

...
array[swp2] = temp;
...

Stack<Card> r = new Stack<Card>();
r.Push(array[i]);
```

You are really pushing an object to your stack. I'm really wondering that this code can compile. In Visual Studio it is not possible.

A simple solution is to use Card/Card[] instead of object there.

By the way I see another problem in your code:

```
Keeper temp = new Keeper();

temp.id = 1;
temp.name = "The Ball";
deck.Push(temp);

temp.id = 2;
temp.name = "The Stick";
deck.Push(temp);
```

temp always references to the same instance. So in the following lines you edit just the values of the same keeper/action/whatever and push the same reference again, again and again.

Comment: Ahh okay, I'm too used to java linked linked list, so I figured it would work the same way. Just to make sure im understanding this correctly, when I push temp it doesn't save the data for temp in the stack? Because what I'm trying to do is just use the stack for data storage.

Comment: If you call Push(), only a reference to your data will be stored! You have to call temp = new Keeper() between push and the data changing code.

Comment: Alright, I'll add that now, and thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you really think you need to use `Stack<Object>`, a simple `as` would work :

```
var st = new Stack<object>();
st.Push("abc");
string str = st.Pop() as string;
```

If you are using:

```
Stack st1 = new Stack();
```

You can add a directive `using System.Collections.Generic;` and use:

```
Stack<Card> st1 = new Stack<Card>();
```